# OS X /cores/ directory taking up 200GB after a couple of months

Tags: macos

I have an almost new macbook pro (~2 months old now) that has managed to accumulate 200gb worth of core dumps in the `/cores` directory.

How can I find out what is causing this?

Comment: Open the `console` app and checkout. That might be useful.

Comment: See this [AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80548/is-there-any-potential-problem-with-disabling-core-dumps) page for more info about disabling core dumps.

Comment: @jherran I don't remember changing any settings and it has filled up my hard drive (250gb SSD) in 2 months of owning the laptop. For less technical users who don't know how to identify this sort of thing, how is this acceptable?

Comment: Some app or apps you are running (or an OS X internal process) is causing a core dump. Looking at the console log for entries at or around the timestamp on the coredump file will help identify what app/process is crapping out. Code dumps can be disabled, if you follow the link in my comment above. Core dumps can indicate serious problems or just sloppy programming. As for acceptability, it is what is it.

Comment: Something must have enabled core dumps, because it's not the default.  Try running "file coredumpname" to see if it shows the name of the process.